# Добавил файл в веб-интерфейсе github. Как подгрузить его на локальный репозиторий?

Tags: git, github

Добавил файл лицензии через интерфейс github. 
Какие команды надо использовать чтобы можно было с ним работать и на локальном репозитории?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2 - будет полезно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого используется команда `git pull`

Answer (score 1):

1. `git clone url_репозитория_заканчивающийся_на_.git` для того, чтобы скачать проект к себе на компьютер
2. `git add .` чтобы добавить изменения в commit. `.` после **add** означает, что мы добавляем все изменения
3. `git commit -m "комментарий к коммиту"` собираем коммит
4. `git push origin master` слово **push** означает, чтобы отправляет изменения, **origin** означает, что на удаленный сервер, а **master** указавает на ветку

Comment: У меня проект уже скачан на компьютер. Я делаю коммиты, как через консоль(с помощью как раз тех команд что Вы описали - add -> commit -> push), так и через интерфейс Intellij IDEA. Они корректно отображаются на github.
Но тут я создал файл LICENSE.md через интерфейс github, и мне надо наоборот подгрузить его в локальный репозиторий.
Неужели для этого надо снова клонировать проект полностью?

Comment: тогда вы не точно описали проблему в вопросе, это команда `git pull`